# mysql query speed at table which has 1.5million rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

It takes around 5 seconds to get result of query from a table consisting 1.5 million row. Query is "select * from table where code=x"

Is there a setting to increase speed ? Or should I jump to another database apart from MySQL ?

Comment: Use indexes to speed up your queries. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

You could index the `code` column. Note that the trade off is that inserting new rows or updating the `code` column on existing rows will be slowed down a bit since the index also needs to be updated. In any event, you should benchmark the improvement to make sure it's worth it.

Comment: indexing resulted with longer query time. my table is about vehicle parts and includes a large data for each part that it's used on each vehicle model with a row columns are: PART CODE - BRAND - MODEL - MAUIN CATEGORY - SUB CATEGORY.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE code=x` -- needs `INDEX(code)`

`SELECT *` when many of the columns are bulky:  Large columns are stored "off-record".  Hence they take longer to fetch.  So, explicitly list the columns you really need, hoping to leave out some of the bulky columns.

When a `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` is involved, it is sometimes best to do

```
SELECT lots of columns
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM t WHERE ... group-by or limit ) AS x
    JOIN t AS y USING(id)
    etc.
```

That is, start by finding just the ids as simply as possible, *then* `JOIN` back to the original table and other table(s).  (This is not the case you presented, but I worry that you over-simplified it.)